# Unwanted scroll bar on the left side of a div?

Tags: javascript, css, google-closure-library

For some reason, there is a scroll bar on the left side of #mainView div inside this page. I really don't understand why. The problem seems to occur in pretty much all browsers. The scroll bar on the left side disappears once the right one is triggered.

[The website](http://www.niuzly.com/p/5053df08ea39d36930000001/2012-9-17)

Comment: I don't see any scroll bar on the left side using Chrome.

Comment: Don't happen in IE9. <div id="mainView" style="left: 200px; top: 51px; height: 820px; overflow: scroll; padding-bottom: 40px; position: absolute;">

Comment: Firefox works fine as well. Try clearing your cache and refreshing the page.

Comment: Oh Yes. It's comimg from overflow: scroll;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before `#mainView` content is loaded, its `width` is null and its `overflow` property is set to `scroll`. So you have a 20px wide `div` with a lone scroll while waiting for content loading.

You can either a width for `#mainView` or try `overflow: auto`.

Answer (score 0):

in simple terms when you set the div to the css property value to overflow the the browser by default will show you the scroll-pane.but if you still want the same  effect of having overflow contents when they fill the div use the css property overflow:auto